# Possible to target a list of nth-of-type(x) at once in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to see if this is possible. Currently, I have quite a few declarations like:

```
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(1),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(2),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(3),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(5),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(6),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(7),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(8),
#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(9)
```

I know you can pass in stuff like 3n, "odd", "even" etc... but can I pass in a list of element IDs? ie

`#filtersBarInner.closed div[class^="pure-u"]:nth-of-type(1,2,5,6,7,8,9)`

I guess I'm being a bit wishful thinking, but thought I would ask in case I've missed anything in the spec.

**BTW:** I need to select different values each time - so I can't use a divisive value.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: nth of type is an elemental selector so there is no need for the `[class^="pure-u"]` as that won't be taken into account when it is applied,  if you have a list of ids, then why pass it into nth-of-type, why not style them directly?

Comment: Or just use a class and apply it to the ones you need that style on

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I'm going to have a go at trying to clean the html up a bit. It started small enough, but with the responsive side of things it got a bit messy with what I'm trying to do

Comment: There is nothing in the spec for this, [I discussed it with the CSSWG a couple of years ago](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jun/0260.html) and the resolution was that it would complicate the grammar just a little too much, as selectors-4 already allows comma-separated selector arguments in :nth-child(). Also see the duplicate.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Question seems pretty clear: the asker wants to pass a list of arbitrary numbers into :nth-of-type(), because it's not possible to write a single An+B expression covering all the cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SCSS you can create a list of elements you want to select and then use `@each` loop on that list with `nth-of-type` selector. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2689/)

```
$list: 1 4 5;

@each $n in $list {
  div:nth-of-type($n) {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've not use SCSS before, but I think I may give it a go :)

Comment: I'm playing with SCSS but your example gives me: `div:nth-of-type($n) { background: blue; }` 3 times, instead of the numbers. What am I doing wrong? Very cool tool otherwise! Going to play a bit more tomorrow, as I can see it being very helpful with bigger projects

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, 3 times because there are 3 elements in the list so elements with those indexes will be selected, If you add one more you can see the result changes https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2690/

Comment: I see the problem :) I needed: `div:nth-of-type(#{$n}) {` , not `div:nth-of-type($n) {` ... maybe a version thing? (I'm using http://sass-lang.com/install )

Answer (score 1):

You can try to simulate your selection by something like this:

```css
div:nth-of-type(n) {
  background: red;
  /* initial styles */
}

div:nth-of-type(n+3) {/* The start is 3*/
  background: green;
  /* new styles */
}

div:nth-of-type(n+9) {/* The end is 9-1 = 8*/
  background: red;
  /* put back the initial styles */
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
```

It can also work with many intervals:

```css
div:nth-of-type(n) {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  background: green;
}
div:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-of-type(n+7) {
  background: green;
}
div:nth-of-type(n+9) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
```

By the way, I suggest to better use LESS/SASS for such things like described in the answer of @Nenad Vracar **OR** simply consider a better HTML/CSS structure to be able to use Classes and ID correctly. Your selection can clearly be improved if you simply append a class to the needed element.